# Thin font-weight does not apply to fonts in other languages

Tags: html, css, fonts, hebrew

While I can apply heavy (400+) weights to languages other than English (Hebrew at the moment) I cannot do so with light weights (300 and lower)

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div>
  <h6>Hello to you<h6>
  <p class="light">Selling you something with elegant font weight contrast.</p
  </div>
  <h6 class="rtl">שלום לכם<h6>
    <p class="light rtl">מוכר לכם משהו אבל באסה כי המשקל לא עובד ככה.</p>

  <h6 class="rtl">שלום לכם<h6>
  <p class="light rtl heavy">מוכר לכם משהו אבל באסה כי המשקל לא עובד ככה.</p  

  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
  }
  .light {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#4c4c4c;
    margin:0;
  }
.heavy {
  font-weight:900;
}
h6 {
  font-size:24px;
  margin:0;
  color:#696f72;
}
div {
  margin:0;
}
.rtl {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

[Code pen example](http://codepen.io/KungFuPandemonium/pen/oLzMvZ)

Comment: Fonts aren't magic; unless you're using a system font, saying "I want thin" will do nothing unless you first tell the CSS which physical font file to load for the specific font family and weight combination you need, through an `@font-face` declaration. And even then, the font you're loading needs to support the text you're styling with it, so even if you have an `@font-face` rule set up, if the text you're styling doesn't have the language you need, the browser will load whatever fallback font in the stack, or just "whatever serif font is available" as last-ditch attempt. Usually Roman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **14** Font Families in [Google Fonts which support Hebrew language](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=hebrew) and **Open Sans** is not one of them.

But since **Open Sans** is widely used font, others font artists extend the font family to support Hebrew language and you can find it on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Open/Open%20Sans%20Hebrew/TTF).

Comment: I just assumed Open Sans worked because 1) Applying it changes the apperance from the default Arial and 2) dev tools showed it applying as "Open Sans" in the font section. How come it showed in the dev tools?

Comment: There is a **font-fallback** logic in all modern browsers. It first tries your selected font (which is Open Sans). If it is not supporting the language, it takes a font which supports that language from the same family (*sans-serif*).

Comment: It may be confusing but it is still a good idea to show a close substitute for missing glyphs.